# Unable to access shell on ssh

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have added the following line to my .bashrc file to start gnu screen on login:

```
exec screen
```

But it seems to go in a loop (may be that is its starting screen also on screen start).

I am not able to access the shell by ssh anymore.

How can this be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Ubuntu recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

If that does not work, I suggest using [PartedMagic USB stick](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=creating_the_liveusb) to boot from and repair your system. You can prepare it using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Using PartedMagic you can mount partitions on your hard drive and edit offending lines from your `/home/username/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables set by screen to do a simple test.

```
if [ "$TERM" != screen ] ; then exec screen ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put that in your `.bashrc`. The first thing `screen` does is starts a shell, which will execute `.bashrc`, which execs screen, etc. How are you logging in? If via `ssh`, just use

```
ssh remotehost screen
```

To fix the immediate problem, you can login using a different shell so that you can edit your `.bashrc`. It's very unlikely you don't have one of `csh` or `zsh` installed:

```
ssh remotehost csh
```

or

```
ssh remotehost zsh
```